# Extract parts of string from a longer string using regex

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with a particular problem. I had downloaded listings for marketing purposes into a CSV file but I have the ability to use regex on the fields. I have managed the regex for the other fields but one section is addresses in the following format

**Fallow Field, Pannel, Harrogate, North Yorkshire HG1**

but can also be shorter, such as

**Holly House, Leeds LS12**

I'm looking for some regex to extract each part of the field and separate them out into separate columns. I thought I had succeeded with `(?<=\,)(.*?)(?=\,])` but not getting anywhere. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it from the end of the line. *If* you know the line will always end with a postal code, you can match that:

```
([A-Z]+\d+)$
```

Anything before that, from the last comma forward, will be the city (unless you have cities with a comma in their name – then you're screwed):

```
,([^,]+)\s+([A-Z]+\d+)$
```

Anything before that is a guess, since I don't know what your data looks like. You have to decide what everything up to the final comma means.